# Add days to datetimepicker upon radio button changed

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a two date input box `Date From` and `Date To` and two radio buttons.

The first radio button will add 5 days while the second radio button will add 10 days to the `Date To`.

How to trigger the `Date To` upon radio button change?

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format : "YYYY-MM-DD"
});

function fn_toggleExpDateOut(e){
  var days = 0;
  var sel = $('input[name=rb]:checked').val() || 0;
  var dateto = e.date.add(+sel || 0, 'days');
  
  $('#dateto').val(dateto.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

$('#datefrom').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function(e) {
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(e);
});

$('input[type=radio][name=rb]').on('change', function() {
  // How to update the Date To?
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6">
<input id="datefrom" name="datefrom" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<input id="dateto" name="dateto" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_five" name="rb" value="5" /> <label for="rb5">Top <small>Add 5 days</small></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_ten" name="rb" value="10" /> <label for="rb10">Standard <small>Add 10 days</small></label>
</div>
```

Comment: `How to trigger` Do you mean that you want to change the value of the `dateTo` input?

Comment: Did you try 'click' instead of 'change'? It would be like

$('input[type=radio][name=rb]').on('click', function() {
  // How to update the Date To?
})

Comment: The `Date To` is relied on the radio buttons below, so if I select any radio button, the Date To should automatically add 5 or 10 days respective to the radio button value. All reference I found online were using datetimepicker `e` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to run the same function you run on `fromDate` change. Just pass it the current `fromDate`

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format : "YYYY-MM-DD"
});

function fn_toggleExpDateOut(date) {
  var days = 0;
  var sel = $('input[name=rb]:checked').val() || 0;
  console.log('sel', sel)
  var dateto = date.add(+sel || 0, 'days');
  
  $('#dateto').val(dateto.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

$('#datefrom').on('dp.change', function(e) {
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(e.date);
});

$('input[type=radio][name=rb]').on('change', function() {
  var fromDate = $('#datefrom').data('DateTimePicker').date();
  if (fromDate) {
    fn_toggleExpDateOut(fromDate);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6">
<input id="datefrom" name="datefrom" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<input id="dateto" name="dateto" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_five" name="rb" value="5" /> <label for="rb5">Top <small>Add 5 days</small></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_ten" name="rb" value="10" /> <label for="rb10">Standard <small>Add 10 days</small></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the same `fn_toggleExpDateOut` on your `radio` button `change` event handler, with an extra parameter for `days`.

```
var days = 0;

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
});

function fn_toggleExpDateOut(days) {
  var dateto = $("#datefrom").data('DateTimePicker').date().add(days, 'days');
  $('#dateto').val(dateto.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

$('#datefrom').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function(e) {
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(days);
});

$('input[type=radio][name=rb]').on('change', function(e) {
  days = parseInt($(this).val());
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(days);
});
```

**Note:**

- I edited your `fn_toggleExpDateOut()` function slightly, so it
  accepts only `days` as param, and edit the `dateto` datetimepicker value
  according the passed params.
- I also made the `days` variable global, so it can be accessed/changed
  in the `change` event handler and in `fn_toggleExpDateOut` as well,
  and added a global `date` variable to hold the `datefrom` date value.

**Demo:**

```js
var days = 0;

$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: "YYYY-MM-DD"
});

function fn_toggleExpDateOut(days) {
  var dateto = $("#datefrom").data('DateTimePicker').date().add(days, 'days');
  $('#dateto').val(dateto.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

$('#datefrom').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function(e) {
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(days);
});

$('input[type=radio][name=rb]').on('change', function(e) {
  days = parseInt($(this).val());
  fn_toggleExpDateOut(days);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input id="datefrom" name="datefrom" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input id="dateto" name="dateto" type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_five" name="rb" value="5" /> <label for="rb5">Top <small>Add 5 days</small></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <input type="radio" id="rb_ten" name="rb" value="10" /> <label for="rb10">Standard <small>Add 10 days</small></label>
</div>
```